# Was the SK-1 spacesuit tested in flight prior to Gagarin's historic mission?

Tags: spacesuits, testing, vostok-program

April 12 is the 60th anniversary of the first human spaceflight, [Vostok 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vostok_1).  As no human had previously been to space, it was also a test of the [SK-1 spacesuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SK-1_spacesuit) that cosmonaut Yuri Gagarin wore.

[This question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/3060/26446) asks about how early spacesuits were tested; the answer explains that they were laboratory tested in a vacuum chamber.  **Was the SK-1 actually tested in an aircraft or spacecraft prior to Gagarin's flight?**

---

*This is the first of [6 questions honoring the 60th anniversary of Vostok 1, the first human spaceflight](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1746/26446).*

Answer (score 13):

> Прототипом первого космического скафандра СК-1 был высотный костюм «Воркута», разработанный для летчиков истребителя-перехватчика Су-9.
>
> Важнейшей отличительной чертой стал шлем, который при падении давления автоматически захлопывал забрало. Для этого в шлем был встроен специальный датчик.

The prototype of the first space suit SK-1 was the Vorkuta high-altitude suit, developed for the pilots of the Su-9 fighter-interceptor.

The most important distinguishing feature was the helmet, which automatically slammed the visor when the pressure dropped. For this, a special sensor was built into the helmet.

https://www.ng.ru/science/2018-07-12/100_skafandr120718.html

P.S. @horsh
This poster probably shows the Vorkuta helmet or a close analogue.
[image]

Comment: A picture of Vorkuta suit http://www.russianarms.ru/forum/index.php?action=dlattach;topic=9386.0;attach=81395;image

Comment: @horsh it is interesting that on the first posters Gagarin was portrayed in a different helmet than in reality.